# Writing a text file to azure web site line by line

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, streamwriter

I have a web app that I need to change to work with Windows Azure Web Sites. Two text file are uploaded and parsed then a third file is written line by line with the parsed data. I've found that I can't upload files directly to an Azure Web Site and need to use Blob Storage. This is pretty straight forward. What I am unable to find is how to write a text file line by line to a Blob or maybe there would be a better solution? I need to re-create this code to work with an Azure Web Site:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
        {
           foreach (Product product in pm.GetAll())
            {
                    fp = pm.MakeFinal(product);

                    curLine.Append(fp.InventoryNumber + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.SellerCost + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.RetailPrice + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.StartingBid + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.BINPrice + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.CAPrice + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.Weight + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.Length + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.Width + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.Height + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.Brand + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.Manufacturer + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.MPN + "\t");
                    curLine.Append(fp.Quantity);

                    writer.WriteLine(curLine.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to use a streamwriter to write a text file line by line to an Azure Blob. If not, what would be a good alternative way to do this?

Edit ------------------------------

This doesn't answer the question I asked but I no longer need to use Azure blob storage. I added the following to my web.config and both files upload fine, the third file is being created fine also:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: What makes you say this: *I've found that I can't upload files directly to an Azure Web Site*?

Comment: @AmitApple I have two files I need to upload, one is 1.75mb the other is about 45mb. The 1.75 mb file uploads fine but for some reason the 45mb file doesn't show up in the upload directory when I verify via ftp.

Comment: This says that azure blobs can't be more than 4mb or they need to be split into blocks.
http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/windows-azure-blobs-and-blocks/

Comment: Correction: Blobs may be up to 200GB. All blobs are made up of blocks (or pages, for page blobs). Each *block* in a blob is limited to 4MB. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691964.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have local disk access, where you can construct your new file exactly how you're doing it now. Once you finish constructing the file, you can just copy the file to a blob (which *is* supported via the blob REST API, and wrapped by the .NET SDK and other language SDKs). Just look at the `CloudBlockBlob` class and the methods `UploadFromFile`and `UploadFromFileAsync`(there are also methods to upload from stream).

There's also a `CloudBlobStream` class that supports reading and writing.

Comment: If I can do that is it appropriate to skip copying it to a blob and just let the file sit on the azure web site?

Comment: I think there is no guarantee that the files will be retained following maintenance / reboot of the instance.  Best bet would be to use local disk to build the file as you described, and then move it to blob storage for persistence.

Comment: Azure Web Sites have shared disk between instances. But, as @BrendanGreen said, it won't last forever. If you ever take down the web site, *all* data is gone. If you store data in blobs, the data survives even if you completely dismantle the web site. Plus, Web Sites have from 1gb to 50gb storage (depending on free/shared/basic/standard tier). Blob storage will give you 1TB per storage account, and you can have multiple storage accounts. And... with blobs, you can have geo-replicated data.